# Only update parts of a collection mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make an API function that updates a collection, however, I can not find a way to do so without making some of the values null. Because it is not guaranteed what the user will update, I want to keep the things that they don't update static in the collection. Here is my current code.

```
try {
        const newOrder = {
            fullName: req.body.fullName,
            email: req.body.email,
            store: req.body.store,
            items: req.body.items,
            address: req.body.address,
            phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber
        }
        const updatedOrder = await Order.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, newOrder)
        res.json(updatedOrder)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json("Error: " + err)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods of doing it.

```
const updateObj = {};
if (req.body.fullName) updateObj.fullName = req.body.fullName;
if (req.body.store) updateObj.store = req.body.store;
if (req.body.email) updateObj.email = req.body.email;
if (req.body.items) updateObj.items = req.body.items;
if (req.body.address) updateObj.address = req.body.address;
if (req.body.phoneNumber) updateObj.phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
try {
    const updatedOrder = await Order.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, updateObj,{new : true})
    res.json(updatedOrder)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json("Error: " + err)
    }
```

Or you can also try something like this

```
const order = await Order.findOne(req.params.id);
order.fullName = (req.body.fullName) ? req.body.fullName : order.fullName;
order.store = (req.body.store) ? req.body.store : order.store;
order.items = (req.body.items) ? req.body.items : order.items;
order.address = (req.body.address) ? req.body.address : order.address;
return await order.save()
```

Or you can use lodash

```
let newOrder = {
            fullName: req.body.fullName,
            email: req.body.email,
            store: req.body.store,
            items: req.body.items,
            address: req.body.address,
            phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber
        }
newOrder = _.pickBy(newOrder, _.identity);
const updatedOrder = await Order.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, newOrder)
res.json(updatedOrder)
```

Comment: Thank you... I decided to use the mongoose $set query... sorry for the trouble and thank you for responding